# How to practice guitar in Minor?

Tags: practice, sight-reading

I practiced Major key for my guitar using "Catholic Book of Worship" and it was an unbelievably huge help not only for sight reading but also for understanding music theory too.

But the problem is minor key. Now that I have faced minor keys, I have to find another source for music scores in minor.

Are there any books or archives on the internet that have songs in minor, hopefully as simple as the ones in "Catholic Book of Worship"?

Comment: All of them, I guess. Songs in a minor key are by no means rare. It would be much harder to find a songbook without any songs in a minor key than with.

Comment: if you had such success with the Worship book, my recommendation would be to mark the notes in the book's pieces that have to be flattened for minor, and play the pieces in minor
.
That way you practice also improvising the conversion to minor